# Keyframes Not Showing in Dope Sheet

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm trying to make a simple walk cycle. I've moved the armature to a position I want. I opened the dope sheet, then the action editor, changed the name and saved it, selected LotRot, selected the whole armature in pose mode and hit 'I' in the dope sheet. I get a selection of 'All Channels', 'Selected Channels' and 'In Active Group'. I've tried all of them and I'm not getting any keyframes.

What am I missing?

Blend File: [image]

Comment: The 'I' in the dopesheet only adds new keyframes to values that have already been keyed. Start by adding keyframes in the 3DView.

Comment: Yup that was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press <kbd>I</kbd> over the 3D window and choose LocRot from the drop-down menu, the keyframe pop up immediately for the selected bone. Perhaps you were pushing <kbd>I</kbd> while your mouse was in another window?

I see you have changed LocRot in the automatic record field, which will do nothing unless you activate it by pushing the red button. After activation move bones to your hearts content. Despite the auto-function - general practise is to select you bones in the 3D window and manually set the first keyframes as described above. If you wish to do automatic key framing, understand it will record everything including your mistakes. Advise tuning that off unless you specifically need it.

Comment: Yup. I had actually made a walking animation a while ago and forgot about that small detail. Thanks.