# Bone not in Dope Sheet

Tags: animation

I animated a model via pose mode and the Dope Sheet.  All was good.  Then I decided to add a bone.  I added the bone by extruding from an existing bone and all was good.  My weight paint appears good as I can move the body part (chin) that I want to move however I cant keyframe the animation because the bone isnt listed in the Dope Sheet.  How does one add or subtract a deleted bone from the Dope Sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyframes Not Showing in Dope Sheet](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63549/keyframes-not-showing-in-dope-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as this post

[Keyframes Not Showing in Dope Sheet](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63549/keyframes-not-showing-in-dope-sheet)

i, aka submit a keyframe, in 3d View first, this will add that bone to the dope sheet.